# How to return to line in file java

Tags: java

I need to add items  to combobox from externel file (java).My problem is that it read just the first line and this is my code:

```
File Names_File = new File("Data" + File.separator + "C://Users//Hatem//Desktop//FichAdr.txt");
FileInputStream fis = null;
BufferedInputStream bis = null;
DataInputStream dis = null;

String str_Data = ""; //For storing the input from the file.

try
{
  fis = new FileInputStream("C://Users//Hatem//Desktop//FichAdr.txt");

  // Here BufferedInputStream is added for fast reading.
  bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
  dis = new DataInputStream(bis);


  str_Data = dis.readLine(); //Reading the line from the file.

  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str_Data); //Tokenizing the line.

  //The below line adds only one item. The objective is adding all the items.

  //*** Requesting help here ***

  jComboBox1.addItem(st.nextToken("|"));

  //*** Requesting help here ***

  // Disposing and closing all the resources after using them.
  fis.close();
  bis.close();
  dis.close();
}

catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    System.err.println("Error: File not found!");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: File not found!", "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}

catch (IOException e)
{
    System.err.println("Error: Unable to read from file!");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Unable to read from file!", "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

I'm debutant in programming can someone help me to resolve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: [A quick glance at the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine()) suggests that you shouldn't be reading lines like this anyway.  Use a `Scanner` or the new `Files` API instead from Java 7 to make this a ton simpler for you.

Comment: You're only calling readLine once. You need to loop until it has reached the end of the file.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line? File Names_File = new File("Data" + File.separator + "C://Users//Hatem//Desktop//FichAdr.txt");
What does "Data" + File.separator mean?

Comment: Sorry,it is a typing mistake:the first time I use stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use loop like:

```
while((str_data = dis.readLine()) != null){
         parse your line here
}
```

Additional parentheses increase priority of instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Loop while you have more tokens:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str_Data, "|"); //Tokenizing the line.

//The below line adds only one item. The objective is adding all the items.

//*** Requesting help here ***
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    jComboBox1.addItem(st.nextToken());
}

//*** Requesting help here ***
```